# Look for post in Facebook

Tags: facebook, search

I'm working on some infographics on my personal Facebook account. I want to query all posts I liked of a certain friend in the last 2 years.

Can someone help me?

I'm not a PHP coder, but I have background on Java and Python. I have tried to look for something [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/) but didn't find anything suitable. Maybe the wrong API?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, definitely wrong API if you are not a php programmer. You need to look the Graph API of Facebook here: [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/). There you have all you need. There is also python modules implementing the Graph API, one example is *pyfacebook* i think.

Basically all you need to know is how to make requests from python to the *internet* in general.

The way you pull posts is with the parameter *feed* in the Graph API (look for that in the page i sent) and the ID is the one of your friend (or any user).

You also need to request an Access_token, but that's another point, and there are millions of posts about it.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

The Graph API documentation can be found at http://graph.facebook.com

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/ is an *SDK* which uses the Facebook API

To get your friend's posts you will need the `read_stream` permission and this call to the API

```
/FRIEND_ID/posts?fields=likes
```

you will need to grab all the paginated data to get all the post from the user

From there, within Python, look in the `fields` parameter for your Facebook ID so that you can prune the posts that do contain likes you have made.

For example, using the Facepy library you can do something *dirty* like

```python
from facepy import GraphAPI

graph = GraphAPI('YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN')

pages = graph.get("FRIEND_ID/posts?fields=likes,story", page=True)

for page in pages:
    for post in page["data"]:
        if "likes" in post:
            for person in post["likes"]["data"]:
                if person["id"] == "YOUR_ID":
                    if "story" in post:
                        print post["story"]
                    print post["id"]
```

<sub>For more information on pagination using Python see: http://philippeharewood.com/facebook/dealing-with-facebook-pagination-the-basic-sauce/</sub>